# Anyway with Locust Web UI to specify tasks with a certain tag to run?

Tags: locust

Anyway with Locust Web UI to specify tasks with a certain tag to run?

So right now we are limited with load tests in certain environments, and ramping up the services under load just doesn't produce the same results as in production. Short term we would like to tag certain tests and run those under isolation to get the same results as in production until we have the infrastructure in place in all environments. I know you can run tasks with a certain tag through the CLI but is there anyway to do this through the Web UI? Can you customize the Web UI to do this, which may be the better question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locust has no native way of choosing tasks to run in the web UI. There is [an open request](https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1695) for that feature but nobody has submitted a PR for it yet.

You can, however, [extend the web UI](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#extending-web-ui) to do whatever you want. You can either add routes like this:

```
from locust import events

@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(web_ui, **kw):
    @web_ui.app.route("/added_page")
    def my_added_page():
        return "Another page"
```

Or you can use [Flask Blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/) and [templates](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/) and create whatever functionality to the UI that you want.